# JsonParseException: Invalid JSON input. Position: 9. Character: '.'

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb, mongorepository

I am using MongoDB with `Spring Boot 2.0.1.RELEASE`. Everything seems to be working fine. I am able to perform CRUD operations properly using MongoRepository. When I use mongodb query in  like

```
@Query(value = "{address.city:?0}")
public List<Hotel> findByCity(String city);

@Query(value = "{address.country:?0}")
public List<Hotel> findByCountry(String country);
```

When I try to access data using the url `localhost:8090/hotels/address/city/Rome`, I get the following error in response

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-05-04T04:51:43.549+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Invalid JSON input. Position: 9. Character: '.'.",
    "path": "/hotels/address/city/rome"
}
```

and the following log in console:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.bson.json.JsonParseException: Invalid JSON input. Position: 9. Character: '.'.] with root cause

org.bson.json.JsonParseException: Invalid JSON input. Position: 9. Character: '.'.
```

I don't know why I am getting `Invalid JSON input. Position: 9. Character: '.'.` when I am performing `GET` request?

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Missing quotes; `@Query(value = "{'address.country':?0}")`

Comment: thank you!!! that solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

Missing quotes; `@Query(value = "{'address.country':?0}")`

– Neil Lunn

That worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

It can arise if you are missing quotes or it can be due to unparsed string passed to MongoDB. Try using parsed string like `\"appname\":1`. This is an example of projection.